# Not in scope: data constructor in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Please tell me what is the problem?

```
data Stack' v = Stack' [v] Int deriving (Show)
...
type StackInt = Stack' Int 

main = print(StackInt [1,2,3] 4)
```

The error i am getting is

```
Not in scope: data constructor `Stackint'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It looks to me like you are confusing the concepts of types and constructors, this is a common problem as they live in separate namespaces and are often given the same name. In the Haskell expression

```
data SomeType = SomeType Int
```

say, you are actually defining the type `SomeType` and a *constructor* `SomeType`. The type is not a function in the normal sense, but the constructor is. If you asked ghci for the type of SomeType you would get this:

```
:t SomeType
SomeType :: Int -> SomeType
```

Now, a `type` declaration is just a shorthand for a longer type definition, in your case making `StackInt` a synonym of `Stack' Int`. But in order to construct a value of this type you still need to use the constructor `Stack'` (which has type `[v] -> Int -> Stack' v`). So your code should be

```
data Stack' v = Stack' [v] Int deriving (Show)

main = print(Stack' [1,2,3] 4)
```

If you wanted to be sure that the type was `Stack' Int` then you could add a function

```
data Stack' v = Stack' [v] Int deriving (Show)

stackInt :: [Int] -> Int -> Stack' Int
stackInt list i = Stack' list i

main = print(stackInt [1,2,3] 4)
```

EDIT: Not also that I've written `stackInt list i = Stack' list i` for transparency here, but you can write it more elegantly just as `stackInt = Stack'`. It is the type constraint that makes sure that you get the right type here.

You could also have both the new function and the type synonym if you wanted, ie

```
data Stack' v = Stack' [v] Int deriving (Show)
type StackInt = Stack' Int

stackInt :: [Int] -> Int -> StackInt
stackInt list i = Stack' list i

main = print(stackInt [1,2,3] 4)
```

Answer (score 16):

The name of the constructor is `Stack'`, not `StackInt`. Creating a type alias using `type` does not create an alias for the constructors (which wouldn't make sense since there may be many constructors for the type and their names don't have to be related the type name at all).

Answer (score 2):

There is no data constructor called `Stackint`. `Stackint` as defined by your `type` declaration is a *type* constructor.

The data constructor is, as for `Stack'`, `Stack'`, although thanks to the type synonym it'll have type `Int -> Stack' Int` instead of `a -> Stack' a`.